# Need to generate columns dynamically

Tags: javascript

I need to dynamically create tables one beside the other. So I have created a table(outer) and am trying to generate columns dynamically on button click. In each of these columns I will create the actual tables(inner) I need, so that in the end they appear side by side.

But I'm stuck at creating columns for the bigger table. Take a look at the code and it will be clear. 
Any solution in JS is appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">    
            function add() {
                var table = document.getElementById('foo');
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;             
                var row =document.getElementById('rowl');         
                var max=table.rows[0].cells.length;
                var cnum;

                if(max==0){
                    cnum=0;
                }else{
                    cnum=max+1;
                }

                var cell1 = row.insertCell(cnum);             

                cell1.innerHTML = "<table id='tabl'"+
                    cnum+
                    "' border=2 bordercolor='RED'><tr><th>Material  "+
                    (cnum+1)+
                    "</th></tr><tr><td>bdfgher</td></tr><tr><td>fdgerh</td></tr></table>"; 
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="add()">Add cell</button>
        <table id="foo" border=1 bordercolor="BLUE">
            <tr id="rowl"></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you need pure js or is jQuery ok?

Comment: I wanted it in js. Have resolved it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
var cell = document.createElement("td");
document.getElementById("rowl").appendChild(cell);
```

Of course, you should add your other elements (inner table) in the cell element.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you a little :)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var c=-1;
function displayResult()
{
var firstRow=document.getElementById("tr_1");
//var x=firstRow.insertCell(-1);
//x.innerHTML="New cell"
var cell1 = firstRow.insertCell(c++);             

                cell1.innerHTML = "<table id='tabl'"+
                    cnum+
                    "' border=2 bordercolor='RED'><tr><th>Material  "+
                    (cnum+1)+
                    "</th></tr><tr><td>bdfgher</td></tr><tr><td>fdgerh</td></tr></table>";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr id='tr_1'></tr>
</table>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Insert cell</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, have resolved the issue. Actually the variable 'cnum' is useless. I have directly used 'max', for cell length.

Comment: sorry for too late response, but glad that you find it useful ;) Cheers